# Unauthorized access for git pushing into branch

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket, git-bash

I am trying to push my local code into the git branch of my team leader which was created by him and given access of write and read to me of branch NOT REPO.
so i want to push my localcode into his branch is this possible? i have read access of master repo and other branch i have access to read and write.

```
$ git push origin branchname
remote: Unauthorized
fatal: Authentication failed for '  https://aniket@bitbucket.org/teamleader/repo.git/'
```

Comment: Can you test pushing to a repository that you own? Are  you meant to be using HTTPS or GIT/SSH as the authentication mechanism? If you have ssh keys then the latter is what you should be using in which case the URL you've used to clone the repository is should be `git@bitbucket.org......` instead of `https://....`

Answer (score 1):

```
☻  git push origin protected 

protected 32adf9f
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 351 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: permission denied to update branch protected
To bitbucket.org:blah/blah.git
 ! [remote rejected] protected -> protected (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@bitbucket.org:blah/blah.git'
```

Based on the output in your question, I do not think there is a problem pushing **to the branch**, but rather there is an authentication problem with **all pushes**.

The command that you are using to push to `branchname` (assuming that that is the branch you have write access to) is correct.

---

<sup>What follows is the output of a failed attempt to push to a **protected github** branch. This is not relevant to the current question but am leaving it here since it might be useful for future readers</sup>

On attempting to push to a protected Github branch, the output is as follows:

```
☻  git push --set-upstream origin master

Counting objects: 11, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (11/11), 1.69 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 11 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2), completed with 2 local objects.
remote: error: GH006: Protected branch update failed for refs/heads/master.
remote: error: At least one approved review is required.
To github.com:blah/blah.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (protected branch hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:blah/blah.git'
```

**Update** Apologies, I just noticed that your repo is on bitbucket and not Github. Have posted updated output for bitbucket.

Comment: Thank you i just want to push it into branchname

Comment: do i need write access to repo? or just to brach it will be okay?